# Which maps SDK allows easy path detection with roadblock?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, mapbox, mapquest

I'm making an iOS/Android app, which allows to see path on map from one point to another. There are a few custom roadblocks, that path finder must avoid. Is there an SDK, that allows such feature? I know Google Maps does not have it.

Answer (score 0):

The [MapQuest directions api](http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/) allows you to either avoid or discourage (control points) a route from a point.